# Sumatoria de Operaciones Agregadas - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Buen día mis estimado coders, un gusto en saludarlos.

En esta ocasión con una duda de SQL.

Tengo una base de datos de transacciones, que me arroja los siguientes datos

```
Descripción    FechaCompra          CantidadComprada  Precio   Costo   CodItem Facturación CodUbic
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Café        2022-07-05 09:29:00.000          1        2.9325    2.55      001       A        0078
Café        2022-07-05 10:16:09.000          1        2.9325    2.55      001       A        0078
Café        2022-07-05 16:10:46.000          1        3.2000    2.55      001       A        0078
Café        2022-07-05 17:00:19.000          1        3.2000    2.55      001       A        0078
```

El detalle es que el Precio de Compra fluctuó a lo largo del día, este es mi código:

```
----Contexto de columna -------
- Facturación = A --> Hace referencia a una compra
- Facturación = B --> Hace referencia a una devolución
Por eso ven, que en el Query resto ambos, para que me el total de compra del producto en el día
- CodUbic --> Las distintas sucursales
- CodItem --> Código del Producto
```

---

```
SELECT
 DISTINCT
  (Descrip1)

,   
    SUM(CASE WHEN
    FACTURACIÓN= 'A' THEN CANTIDADCOMPRADA
    WHEN FACTURACIÓN= 'B' THEN -CANTIDADCOMPRADA END)
 OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(FechaCompra AS DATE), CodUbic, coditem, Descripción)  AS [Cantidad]

 , CodItem
 , CodUbic

 , CAST(FechaCompra AS DATE) Fecha

 ,  
    [Costo]  * SUM(CASE WHEN
    FACTURACIÓN= 'A' THEN CANTIDADCOMPRADA
    WHEN FACTURACIÓN= 'B' THEN -CANTIDADCOMPRADA END)
 OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(FechaCompra AS DATE), CodUbic, coditem, costo) AS [Total Costos]
 

 , 
    [Precio] * (SUM(CASE WHEN
    FACTURACIÓN= 'A' THEN CANTIDADCOMPRADA
    WHEN FACTURACIÓN= 'B' THEN -CANTIDADCOMPRADA END)
 OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(FechaCompra AS DATE), CodUbic, coditem, precio)) AS [Total Venta] 

FROM  TEMFAC

WHERE 
      tipofac IN ('A','B')
    AND 
      codubic = '0078'
    AND 
      coditem = '001'
    AND 
      DAY(FechaCompra) = 5
    AND 
      MONTH(FechaCompra) = 7
    AND 
      YEAR(FechaCompra) = 2022
```

El resultado arrojado es:

```
Descripción   FechaCompra  CantidadComprada       TotalCosto    CodItem  Facturación  CodUbic    TotalVenta
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Café        2022-07-05          4               10.200000       001       A          0078      5.865000
   Café        2022-07-05          4               10.200000       001       A          0078      6.400000
```

El problema es que `Total Venta`, debe esta unificado, dando como final : `12.265`, pero no logro hacer que se unifiquen, claramente, la diferencia nace cuando hago la Función Window y lo divido por el costo el día, pero, el coste cambió en el día y la verdad no sé como hacerlo.

El resultado esperado sería:

```
  Descripción   FechaCompra  CantidadComprada       TotalCosto    CodItem  Facturación  CodUbic    TotalVenta
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      Café        2022-07-05          4               10.200000       001       A        0078      12.265
```

Por supuesto, estoy haciendo esto como resumen del día de todos los productos vendidos para ese día y para las distintas tiendas.

Comment: Si llegaste a probar usando GROUP BY?

Comment: Porque creaste una pregunta nueva, cuando ayer tenis basicamente la misma pregunta y a mi pidiendote aclaraciones sobre la misma?? fijate que el comentario que te dejaron fue lo mismo que te pregunte yo ayer....

Comment: Sí, lo que pasa es que avancé más allá y no hizo falta un GROUP BY.

Comment: Me pediste más detalles, pero avancé sobre lo de ayer, acá quedé en una nueva encrucijada y otra incognita.

Comment: es basicamente la misma pregunta y el problema es el mismo. sigo sin entender, porque no usas simplemente un group by....

Comment: Acá mostré más detalles y un  código más organizado con respecto a ayer

Comment: No puedo utilizar un Group By, porque los costes cambian, esto me arrojará dos datos para el mismo producto y es la duda donde estoy actualmente

Comment: igual, si ya tenias nuestra atencion ayer, podes usar el boton [edit] y agregar toda esa informacion en la pregunta. ahora, que hacemos con la otra?

Comment: que tiene que ver los costes con el group by, si esa columna la vas a sumar? no importa si cambia o no, si lo sumas, se va a sumar... algo me sigue faltando...

Comment: Tenes 3 group by, uno por descripcion que no tiene mucho sentido, otro por costo (no entiendo porque) y otro por precio (no entiendo tampoco por que).. basicamente estas agrupando por 3 campos que son siempre los mismos, eso es un group by, porque para colmo, usas esos campos para hacer sum (aunque sea negativo el numero)....

Comment: y si, es exactamente la misma pregunta que ayer.. solo que agregaste mas campos...